# How to make a JPanel dynamic?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I have a JFrame that has a JPanel inside. I call "setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 600));" but I want the JPanel and its contents to resize when someone resizes the JFrame.

Comment: remove `setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 600));` and leave to layout manager to set the size of `JPanel`.

Comment: What layout are you using for `JPanel` and `JFrame`?

Comment: Please have a look at [A Visual Guide to Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).

Comment: [Don't use `setPreferredSize()` when you really mean to override `getPreferredSize()`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/230513).

Answer (score 1):

BorderLayout is the way to go.  Components start at their preferred size, but are expanded as needed to fill the region they are in.

Answer (score 0):

Set your layout on your frame with BorderLayout
Add your JPanel by

```
frame.add(yourPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

This will allow it to stretch vertically & horizontally

As for the Contents inside a JPanel, give it a layout that will accommodate stretching as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use a layout manager instead of setting the bounds for each component.

It is going to vary from program to program how you want your components to move.

Take a look at [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html) and try to see which layout will work best for you.